# Fit of negative binomial regression model

Tags: r, regression, generalized-linear-model, assumptions

I have ran a negative binomial regression. I'm guessing the use of a negative binomial regression is not ideal given my design, but I'm hoping I can 'get away with it', as it seems to be working fairly well.

Here's my design:

- Count the the total number of geese in a flock
- Count the number of these that are vigilant.
- Then divide number vigilant/number in    flock, to get a percentage
  that are vigilant
- Predictor variables are    flock size (count),    water height in
  metres, date, subspecific identity of the    flock and
  the part of my study site that    the flock were in (ssp.zone)

Below is a plot of my response variable (`alert.integer`)

[image]

Below is a summary of the model

```
Call:
glm.nb(formula = alert.integer ~ ssp * water.height + ssp * ssp.zone + 
    ssp * count + ssp * I(as.Date(datetime)), data = dataScanSampling_sub, 
    init.theta = 1.168496598, link = log)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-3.0035  -0.9556  -0.3382   0.3886   2.0942  

Coefficients:
                                                    Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)                                        3.971e+02  6.239e+01   6.365 1.95e-10 ***
sspLight-bellied Brent Goose                      -4.369e+02  7.294e+01  -5.990 2.10e-09 ***
water.height                                       2.978e-01  8.719e-02   3.415 0.000637 ***
ssp.zonelight zone                                -1.214e+00  2.103e-01  -5.775 7.70e-09 ***
count                                             -5.226e-03  8.506e-04  -6.143 8.09e-10 ***
I(as.Date(datetime))                              -2.461e-02  3.904e-03  -6.303 2.93e-10 ***
sspLight-bellied Brent Goose:water.height          2.743e-03  1.015e-01   0.027 0.978438    
sspLight-bellied Brent Goose:ssp.zonelight zone    1.344e+00  2.635e-01   5.102 3.36e-07 ***
sspLight-bellied Brent Goose:count                 4.174e-03  8.766e-04   4.761 1.93e-06 ***
sspLight-bellied Brent Goose:I(as.Date(datetime))  2.726e-02  4.564e-03   5.973 2.33e-09 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for Negative Binomial(1.1685) family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 558.21  on 367  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 433.87  on 358  degrees of freedom
AIC: 3236.4

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 1


              Theta:  1.1685 
          Std. Err.:  0.0894 

 2 x log-likelihood:  -3214.4300
```

And here are residuals from model:

[image]

So taking into account the description of my design, the plot of the response variable (`alert.integer`), the residuals plot and the output from `summary`(), can I get away with a negative binomial regression model here?

Comment: Why are you using a NB model for a response variable that is not a count? What happens with OLS regression, quantile regression, or possible beta regression?

Comment: The response variable isn't a count, but is still derived from a count. And forgive me if I'm wrong, but its distribution looks like a count. I tried OLS and there were patterns in residuals and I tried beta regression but it wouldn't run as there were zeros in data.

Comment: Oh, OK. Well, the NB is going to assume that the counts are unbounded on the right. It could, therefore, predict values over 100 which would not make sense in your case. But I am not sure of the consequences of violating this.

Comment: I should have mentioned that the goal of running this model is to test whether the two subspecies of geese differ in time spent vigilant, whilst controlling for covariates. I'm not going to use the model as a prediction tool. Would that therefore excuse the model for predicting values > 100?

Comment: Checked the model and it's predicting values between 6 and 128. Would be grateful for any comments on the consequences of this and any potential remedies.